# Check if JSON file matches template- Powershell 5

Tags: json, powershell, compare

I'm looking for a way to check if file provided to the script matches a schema that is required by the script. My powershell version is 5 so no access to Test-Json cmndlet. Any ideas?

JSON schema to be checked against.

```
$json_content = @"
{ 
    "buttons":{
        "1":"Zenek",
        "2":"NetExt"
        },
    "Text":{
        "1":"",
        "2":""
        }
}
"@
```

Example file to be checked (positively)

```
$json_content = @"
{ 
    "buttons":{
        "1":"Zenek",
        "2":"NetExt"
        },
    "Text":{
        "1":"THIS IS OK",
        "2":"CORRECT"
        }
}
"@
```

Example file 2 to be checked (and failed)

```
$json_content = @"
{ 
    "I MADE CHANGES HERE":{
        "1":"Zenek",
        "2":"NetExt"
        },
    "PLEAE FAIL ME":{
        "1":"",
        "2":""
        }
}
"@
```

Comment: You do not have a schema.  You have a template.  Schemas check limits and formatting.  You have just a json with no data.  In this case it looks like you have expected results that you are comparing against actual results.  Some people may call this a schema, I do not.  I prefer to use the word template.  I would use Import-Jason and then compare the two results.

Comment: My bad on the wording. Let's assume I imported all of the above in their separate variables. How would I go about comaping them? Which comparator would be most effective?

Comment: I would compare against a good results, not a json that has no values.  Then import two jason and enumerate through the two object comparing each value.

Answer (score 1):

This approach will compare the `noteproperty` members between 2 PSObjects and will return false if any of the following occurs:

- The template contains properties that are not found in the target.
- The target contains properties that are not found in the template.
- A property which exists in both has different data types.

The basic idea is:

1. Convert the JSON into `psCustomObjects`.
2. Compare the `noteproperties` of the highest level object of the template and target.
3. Recursively compare any properties which are themselves `psCustomObjects` (but return false as soon as a mismatch is found)

Please note that this will only work with `noteproperties`. If you try to compare complex objects containing methods or other property types then this will not work.

Test Data:

```
#this represents the structure that we expect. This is our template
$templateJson = @"
{ 
    "buttons":{
        "1":"Zenek",
        "2":"NetExt"
        },
    "Text":{
        "1":"",
        "2":""
        }
}
"@
$expectedJsonStructure = $templateJson | ConvertFrom-Json

#this is a test case that should be considered valid
$expectPassJSON = @"
{ 
    "buttons":{
        "1":"dummyValue",
        "2":"dummyValue"
        },
    "Text":{
        "1":"dummyValue",
        "2":"dummyValue"
        }
}
"@
$expectPassStructure = $expectPassJSON | ConvertFrom-Json

#this test case should fail because "buttons" is now a [string] instead of a [pscustomobject]
$expectFailJSON = @"
{ 
    "buttons": "Fail on type mismatch",
    "Text":{
        "1":"dummyValue",
        "2":"dummyValue"
        }
}
"@
$expectFailStructure = $expectFailJSON | ConvertFrom-Json

#this test case should fail because "text.1" is now an integer instead of a string
$expectFailJSON2 = @"
{ 
    "buttons":{
        "1":"dummyValue",
        "2":"dummyValue"
        },
    "Text":{
        "1":0,
        "2":"dummyValue"
        }
}
"@
$expectFailStructure2 = $expectFailJSON2 | ConvertFrom-Json

#this test case should fail because the property names do not match the template
$expectFailJSON3 = @"
{ 
    "buttonsDifferentName":{
        "1":"dummyValue",
        "2":"dummyValue"
        },
    "TextDifferentName":{
        "1":"dummyValue",
        "2":"dummyValue"
        }
}
"@
$expectFailStructure3 = $expectFailJSON3 | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Function for comparing the object structures:

```
Function Verify-PSObjectStructure{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][psobject]$template,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][psobject]$target
    )

    #returns false after finding any mismatches

    $anyFail = $false
    $templateProps = $template | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty
    $targetProps = $target | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty

    #check for properties in the template that are not found in the target
    if(@($templateProps.Name).Where({$_ -notin $targetProps.Name}).Count -gt 0){
        return $false
    }

    #check for properties in the target that are not found in the template
    if(@($targetProps.Name).Where({$_ -notin $templateProps.Name}).count -gt 0){
        return $false
    }

    #for all properties shared between the objects, check if their values have the same type
    $sharedProps = @($templateProps.Name).Where({$_ -in $targetProps.Name})
    $sharedProps.ForEach({
        if($template.($_).GetType() -ne $target.($_).GetType()){
            $anyFail = $true
        }
    })

    if($anyFail){
        return $false
    }

    #for any properties that are PSObjects, do a recursive call to compare their properties
    $sharedProps.ForEach({
        if($template.($_).GetType() -eq [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]){
            if( -not(Verify-PSObjectStructure -template $template.$_ -target $target.$_)){
                $anyFail = $true
            } 
        }
    })

    return -not $anyFail
}

#should return True
Verify-PSObjectStructure -template $expectedJsonStructure -target $expectPassStructure
#should return False
Verify-PSObjectStructure -template $expectedJsonStructure -target $expectFailStructure
```

Function for seeing what the custom `Verify-PSObjectStructure` function is doing:

```
Function Explain-PSObjectStructure(){
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][psobject]$template,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][psobject]$target,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][psobject]$objectDescription
    )
    $templateProps = $template | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty
    $targetProps = $target | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty

    Write-Host ([string]::Concat('*** Explaining properties of "', $objectDescription, '" ***'))

    $templatePropertiesNotInTarget = @($templateProps.Name).Where({$_ -notin $targetProps.Name})

    if($templatePropertiesNotInTarget.Count -gt 0){
        Write-Host 'FAIL: Template properties not found in target properties'
        $templatePropertiesNotInTarget | Out-Host
    }
    else{
        Write-Host 'PASS: All properties in the template are found in the target. Shared properties: '
        $templateProps.Name | Out-Host
    }

    $targetPropertiesNotInTemplate = @($targetProps.Name).Where({$_ -notin $templateProps.Name})
    if($targetPropertiesNotInTemplate.count -gt 0){
        Write-Host 'FAIL: Target properties not found in template properties'
        $targetPropertiesNotInTemplate | Out-Host
    }
    else{
        Write-Host 'PASS: All properties in the target are found in the template.'
    }

    $sharedProps = @($templateProps.Name).Where({$_ -in $targetProps.Name})
    $propertiesWithDifferentTypes = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
    $sharedProps.ForEach({
        if($template.($_).GetType() -ne $target.($_).GetType()){
            [string]::Concat('FAIL: Target property "', $_, '" of type "', $target.($_).GetType(), '" does not match the template. Expected type "', $template.($_).GetType(), '"') | Out-Host
            $propertiesWithDifferentTypes.Add($_) | Out-Null
        }
        else{
            [string]::Concat('PASS: Property "', $_, '" type matches between template and target') | Out-Host
        }
    })

    $propertiesThatAreObjects = $sharedProps.ForEach({
        if($template.($_).GetType() -eq [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]){
            $_
        }
    })

    if($propertiesThatAreObjects.Count -gt 0){
        [string]::Concat('Checking properties of all psobjects that belong to "', $objectDescription, '"') | Out-Host
        $propertiesThatAreObjects.Name | Out-Host
    }
    else{
        [string]::Concat('Object "', $objectDescription, '" does not contain any shared properties which are psobjects') | Out-Host
    }

    $propertiesThatAreObjects.ForEach({
        if($_ -in $propertiesWithDifferentTypes){
            [string]::Concat('Property "', $_, '" type does not match between template and target. Skipping detailed comparison') | Out-Host
        }
        else{
            Explain-PSObjectStructure -template $template.$_ -target $target.$_ -objectDescription $_
        }
    })

    [string]::Concat('*** finished processing all properties and child items of "', $objectDescription,'" ***') | Out-Host
}

#all items checked should yield a PASS message
Explain-PSObjectStructure -template $expectedJsonStructure -target $expectPassStructure -objectDescription 'ParentObject'
#at least one item checked should yield a FAIL message
Explain-PSObjectStructure -template $expectedJsonStructure -target $expectFailStructure -objectDescription 'ParentObject'
```

Answer (score -1):

PowerShell 7 comes with `Test-Json`, a command with which you can validate a JSON document against a JSON schema.

First, we'll need to define a schema that describes the required JSON format:

```
$schema = @'
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "buttons": {
      "$ref": "#/$defs/stringtuple"
    },
    "Text": {
      "$ref": "#/$defs/stringtuple"
    }
  },
  "$defs": {
    "stringtuple": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "1": { "type": "string" },
        "2": { "type": "string" }
      }
    }
  },
  "required": ["buttons","Text"]
}
'@
```

Here, we describe a root object with two properties, `buttons` and `Text`, both of which are required to have a value described by the nested `stringtuple` schema - an object that consists of two string properties `1` and `2`.

Now it's simply a question of calling `Test-Json`:

```
$isValidJson = Test-Json $json_content -Schema $schema
```

Comment: I am aware of Test-Json commandlet, but as I mentioned in the original post, I don't have accesss to version above 5.